# What are the odds of exactly 1\500 people hitting a 1\4096 chance? Why does it not remain a static 1/4096?

Tags: statistics

Consider a video game that can potentially reward its players for performing a simple action. However, this reward is only provided randomly on a fixed rate of 1/4096. If 500 players were to perform said simple action, what are the chances that exactly one person (out of the 500) receives the reward?

If the answer does not remain 1/4096, can you demonstrate why that is?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not correct and has multiple errors.

First, if there are $n$ trials, each with independent probability of success $p$, it is not true that the probability $\Pr[A]$ of one successful outcome is $np$.  This should be evident by noting that it is impossible for any probability to exceed $1$, and if $n > 1/p$, your formula leads to an obvious contradiction.  The same flaw exists in your calculation of $\Pr[B]$.

Second, $A$ and $B$ are not independent events, so you cannot write $\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[A]\Pr[B]$.  They are dependent because the number of successes and number of failures in a fixed number of trials always adds up to the number of trials.

To perform the calculation correctly, we specify a random variable that counts the number of successes $X$ in $n$ trials.  So if $X = 1$, that means exactly $1$ success is observed in $n$ trials.

Such a random variable has a binomial distribution, and in your case, with $n = 500$ and $p = 1/4096$.  Its probability mass function is $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} = \binom{500}{x} (1/4096)^x (4095/4096)^{500-x}, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 500\}.$$

So $$\Pr[X = 1] = 500 \frac{4095^{499}}{4096^{500}} \approx 0.10806751438779883411.$$

The fact that your answer happens to be close but not quite equal to the correct answer is a consequence of the fact that:

- $p$ is very small
- $n$ is large but not larger than $1/p$
- you want the probability that exactly $1$ success is observed.

Another way to compute the correct probability without using a binomial distribution is to observe that, among $500$ trials, there are $500$ ways to choose which trial is the success, and for that chosen success (and $499$ failures), the probability of such an outcome is $p(1-p)^{499} = 4095^{499}/4096^{500}$; thus the total probability across all $500$ possible and mutually exclusive choices is $500(4095^{499}/4096^{500})$, as obtained with the binomial distribution above.

Answer (score 1):

No, your answer is wrong, because your analysis analogizes to $500$ different people each selecting an element from the set $\{1,2,3\cdots,4096\}$, when the selection by the group of people as a whole is supposedly done, without replacement.

That isn't how I read the original problem:

> Consider a video game that can potentially reward its players for performing a simple action. However, this reward is only provided randomly on a fixed rate of 1/4096.
> If 500 players were to perform said simple action, what are the chances that exactly one person (out of the 500) receives the reward?

The way that I interpret this, each person's attempt to hit the reward is an independent event, which analogizes to each person selecting an element from $\{1,2,\cdots,4096\}$, with the sampling done, with replacement.

This means that one specific person's probability of winning the reward is unaffected by whether anyone else has won the reward.

So, the probability should be computed by a [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution),
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Here, $n = 500, k = 1, p = \frac{1}{4096},$ and $q = (1-p).$